# I have a question about the effect of a sender channel

Tags: go

I am not clear about why the print statement in `func a1` will not print anything if I remove `<-result` in `func a2`.
I think before we send something into result, the print statement should be executed, and `<-result` should not have some effect on that.

```
func a2(){
    x := 3
    result := make(chan int, 10)
    input := make(chan int, 10)
    go a1(x, input, result)
    input <- 4
    <-result
}

func a1(x int, input <-chan int, result chan<- int){
    y := <-input
    fmt.Println("hello", y)
    result <- x
}
```

However, then I tried the following code: it will print `hello` no matter whether I have `<-result` or not.

```
func a2(){
    x := 3
    result := make(chan int, 10)
    go a1(x, result)
    <-result
}

func a1(x int, result chan<- int){
    fmt.Println("hello")
    result <- x
}
```

Can you explain this in a detailed way so that a beginner can understand this? It seems like `input <-chan int` this input channel is doing something that causes the difference.

Comment: Add enough framing code (`main` function, import statements, etc) to make it runnable on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/) and put a link to that in your question. I think I know what's going on, but can't be sure without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because without <-result, a2() returns and the program terminates, assuming a2() is the only thing main() does. Probably a1() never even wakes up, because input channel is buffered, and writing to it will not block. If you make it unbuffered, then a1() will wake up before a2() returns, but that still doesn't guarantee that println will run.

With <-result, a2() waits for a1() to read from the result channel, which is after println. That's the only safest way to ensure println runs.

Comment: This is the definitive resource: https://golang.org/ref/mem

There is still a possibility that print will not run, because things that happen after a synchronization (channel read/write), until the next synchronization event, are concurrent, meaning there is no ordering guarantees.